# Binding forms ComboBox to DataTable DataContext

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, binding, clr

I'm usually able to solve my problems with about five minutes of searching but this one has taken several days with no results, so I'll try posing the question.

I have a Form whose DataContext is set to a datatable (would prefer LINQ to SQL but I am stuck w/ Sybase which lacks good support for modern entity frameworks.) I have a combo box sourced by another datatable that should update a column on the forms data table but I can't seem to get the binding for SelectedValue to work correctly.

I get a binding error in my Output window which I am unsure how to resolve but it points to the cause of the problem:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'color' property not found on 'object' ''DataTable' (HashCode=1796783)'. BindingExpression:Path=color; DataItem='DataTable' (HashCode=1796783); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='cboColor'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

I've created a sample app that recreates the problem and provide the Xaml and code behind here

Thanks in advance for your help

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestBed.ComboTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ComboTest" Height="300" Width="300"
    Loaded="OnLoad">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="126*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="243" Margin="8,6,0,0" Name="dgList" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="dgList_SelectionChanged"> 
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=name}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=color}" Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="207" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="grdSelection" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,27,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="{Binding Path=color}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,56,0,0" Name="cboColor" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="colorName" SelectedValuePath="colorName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=color}" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="_Save" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,12" Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="btnSave_Click" />
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;

namespace WPFTestBed
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ComboTest.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ComboTest : Window
    {
        public ComboTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private DataTable getList()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("color"));

            row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = "abe";  row["color"] = "Red"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = "bob"; row["color"] = "Yellow"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = "chuck"; row["color"] = "Blue"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = "doug"; row["color"] = "Red"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = "eddie"; row["color"] = "Yellow"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = "fred"; row["color"] = "Blue"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            return dt;
        }

        private DataTable getColors()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colorName"));
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["colorName"] = "Red"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["colorName"] = "Yellow"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = dt.NewRow(); row["colorName"] = "Blue"; dt.Rows.Add(row);
            return dt;
        }

        private void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dgList.DataContext = getList();
            cboColor.DataContext = getColors();
        }

        private void dgList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the selected Item
            DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)dgList.SelectedCells[0].Item;

            //For Illustrative purposes - in "real life" the data table used for the DataContext would come from the database
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("color"));
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow(); row["name"] = selectedRow["name"].ToString();  row["color"] = selectedRow["color"]; dt.Rows.Add(row);

            // Set the data context for the form
            grdSelection.DataContext = dt;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)grdSelection.DataContext;
            // dt is not updated by combobox binding as expected
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you bind the list to the colors, the data context gets screwed up:

```
 cboColor.DataContext = getColors();
```

Need to keep the ComboBox's data context bound to the DataTable.  In the example app, you could do by setting the items source directly and leaving its data context alone:

```
cboColor.ItemsSource = getColors().AsDataView();
```

Comment: Your right, but only with a explicit conversion from DataTable to IEnumerable.

Comment: @LPL not sure I understand you.  I ran the code as is, and it seemed to work.  Why shouldn't you be able to set ItemsSource to a DataTable?

Comment: @dbaseman - I tried setting the ItemsSource as you suggested and got a compile time error:

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Simple cast to IEnumerable wont work.

Comment: @RonChibbyChibnik ah, so LPL was right.  I forgot I had added **AsDataView**.  Please see my update.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks - nice clean solution. Thanks @dbaseman - you 'da man.

Comment: @RonChibbyChibnik ha, thanks.  Well constructed question with a compilable example.

Answer (score 0):

Your ComboBox SelectedValue binding should be bound to colorName.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,56,0,0" Name="cboColor" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="colorName" SelectedValuePath="colorName" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=colorName}" />
```