# how to bind dataSource to combobox?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind data with combobox but couldn't bind it.

`CBFolders.ItemsSource = client.GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync("token", 12, 3427).AsDataView();`

In this code I am using web service which method GetNewsLetterFolders return data table.

Please help me how I can bind this??

Comment: What is the return type of `GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync`?

Comment: How could it possibly return DataTable if it is an async call?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you said DataTable isn't possible to return , then what is suitable to contain and return?

Comment: Can you please show the method signature for GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync

Comment: if it's an async call, shouldn't be awaited?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot  `public DataTable GetNewsLetterFolders(string AuthenticationToken, int SkinID, int SiteID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return type of web service method should be a model class. If it's returning `folderId` & `Description` and both properties should member of `FolderData` class. Hence FolderData essentialy become table.

I consider service method `GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync` returns List. So combox box should be bind like this

```csharp
CBFolders.ItemsSource = await client.GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync("token", 12, 3427);
```

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="CBFolders" SelectedValuePath="folderId" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
```

`SelectedValuePath` should be bind with that property which is needed while selection changes in `ComboBox`. `DisplayMemberPath` should be bind with that property which is needed to show in `ComboBox`.

`CBFolders.SelectedItem` will return selected `folderId`

Comment: return type should be list or model class?

Comment: List of model class i.e. `List<FolderData>`

Comment: I think calss is not serializable in this context so that its not working :( 
any alternate?

Comment: What kind of web service are you using, ASMX, SOAP, WCF, REST? is `DataTable` model class or [`System.Data.DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) ?

Comment: its SOAP. and it returns System.Data.DataTable

Comment: You should use REST or WCF service. ASMX is quite older.

Comment: I hv tried as you said :

[`<ComboBox x:Name="CBFolders" SelectedValuePath="folderId" DisplayMemberPath="Description" / >`]

and code is 

[`CBFolders.ItemsSource = await client.GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync("token", 12, 3427);`]

But I am still confuse how to return list<FolderItem> from webservice because I hv tried but its was not working.

Comment: It will not work directly, have you tried to convert DataTable to List<FolderItem> using loop? You need to change whole web service to get data in List<FolderItem>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465039/binding-forms-combobox-to-datatable-datacontext

Comment: I think List<FolderItem> is better way can you show me example? how we  return this list of class?

Comment: You can create such web service using by WCF service with entity framework. It offers SOAP as well as REST service offering. SOAP returns you data in form of model class' object. REST returns data in form of XML or JSON. You have to deserilize in app. It uses HTTP. Check out [Implementing a WCF Service with Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127395/Implementing-a-WCF-Service-with-Entity-Framework)

Comment: Thanks  @xyroid its working, I was missing some thing your answer is right thanks again (y)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the datatable to List when you are binding it to ItemsSOurce property. CBFolders.ItemsSource = client.GetNewsLetterFoldersAsync("token", 12, 3427).GetList(). Hope this helps.

Comment: I was  using datatable because we need more than one column data of different type, our data table's first column is folderId and second is Description.

can I do this with list?single or 2D?